# Set a lookup field value in dynamics crm for multiple records imported by ssis script

Tags: import, ssis, dynamics-crm, crm

i am pushing data from SQL server using ssis into my custom entity Transaction 
this transaction has a lookup filed Contact and some other simple field like email amount 
i can successfully import data into the crm only when i push email id and amount ,
whenever i try to set lookup field value it require entity reference id , this is where i am stuck in our database there is no entity reference id we only have name

how can i set look up filed value if i don't have entity reference id , since it is a SQL data it has thousand of records

can i set my contact lookup filed value in crm itself based on email id like lets say i imported the data and once the data is imported into crm lookup filed value will set to that particular contact who has the email id which we imported into crm

i hope i am making myself clear please help me out

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inside your script component (I believe you use this approach) you will have to write code that will fetch required data from CRM using RetreiveMultiple queries.

Comment: Hi Andrii,
Is there any way ?
Is it not possible to query and fetch the required data (specially GUID) from CRM through CRM connector (Kingsway Soft) ?

Comment: Can you please help with some links to get guidence in SSIS for this scenario like which specific component needs to be used to retrieve the existing records based on EmpNumber and then update records only if any difference is there between old data and new data ?